# How to trim only alphabets using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have  a scenario where need to trim only alphabets from the string and display numbers and special characters.

```
var abc = "Hai 40.00"; // Output : 40.00
var xyz = "Hai 40.00 - 50.00 Was" // Output : 40.00 - 50.00
```

Any generic way to handle this.

Comment: Can you add an example of the output you expect to see from these strings, and also the attempts you've made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var xyz = "Hai 40.00 - 50.00 Was"
xyz = xyz.replace(/[a-z]*/gi, '').trim();
alert(xyz);
```

1. `[a-z]` : Match all the alphabets
2. `*`     : Matches preceding set zero or more times
3. `g`     : Global flag, not to stop after first match
4. `i`     : Case insensetive match
5. `trim`  : Remove leading and trailing spaces

Comment: `need to trim only alphabets from the string and display numbers and special characters`

Comment: Apply `trim` to the result to remove leading/trailing spaces as well!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this is an accurate answer based on your question. But I believe your trying to remove all characters from each var and leave only the integers, right?

If this is the case, you can use the [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method and pass in a regex value of `\D` which is matches all non-digits.

Here's an example:

```
removeInt = abc.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

Good luck!

Comment: then he wont be getting 40.00 - 50.00 meaning even - and . will be removed

Answer (score 0):

```
var xyz = "Hai 40.00 - 50.00 Was";
xyz = xyz
        .replace(/^\w+/g, '')  // remove leading alpha
        .replace(/\w+$/g, '')  // remove ending alpha
        .trim()                // regular trim
// output = "40.00 - 50.00"
```

You could also merge the two `replace` :

```
var xyz = "Hai 40.00 - 50.00 Was";
xyz.replace(/^\w+(.*?)\w+$/, '$1')
   .trim()
```